# how get current datetime on looping

Tags: python

Begin.. sorry my english very bad

i have some code of python.

```py
def come():
    answer = input('yes or no : ').strip()
    str_datetime = now.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
    if answer == 'yes':
        print('Okay.. {}'.format(answer))
        print(str_datetime)
    else:
        print('Please input yes or no again!')
    come()

come()
```

problem is.. i want to get **str_datetime** always reload (always chanage according to the time to passes.. i mean)

Answer (score 2):

If you initialize the `now` method of `datetime` within the `come` function,
it will be updated every time it is called. Could you try the following?

```
from datetime import datetime

def come():
    now = datetime.now()  # Initialize within the function
    answer = input('yes or no : ').strip()
    str_datetime = now.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
    if answer == 'yes':
        print('Okay.. {}'.format(answer))
        print(str_datetime)
    else:
        print('Please input yes or no again!')
    come()

come()
```

Comment: oooppss..  i forgot the variable now = datetime.now() put out from the def..
thanks.. resolve

Comment: Ok, happy to help.